# Polite way to explain not answering a call

Tags: sentence-construction, politeness

I was in meeting with my mobile in silent mode, so I couldn't answer a call.

What would be the perfect sentence to say this to the caller?

Comment: "Attend a call" usually means "take part in a meeting via telephone" which I don't think is what you mean here. Are you trying to apologize for not answering? Not calling the person back because you didn't see their call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you're trying to apologize for not answering,
I personally would say,

> I'm sorry (that) I missed your call. My phone was on silent.

If I want to make it clear that I was in the meeting, I might add,

> I'm sorry (that) I missed your call. My phone was on silent. I was in a meeting.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry I missed your phone call, but I was in a meeting.

Comment: I don't think "but" is necessary, unless you want to indicate that you are not altogether sorry.

Comment: I don't think it makes you sound less sorry.  It's indicating the situation couldn't be helped.  It's fine without it too.

Comment: This is from the point of view that it's disingenuous to even apologize in this situation (especially if your main point is that it was out of your control). I will also add that I tend to be more sensitive to such things than is necessarily warranted, because it touches on an aspect of personal responsibility that I hold very dear. In my opinion, someone should either take responsibility for their role in the issue ("I didn't anticipate you'd call/didn't tell you I'd be busy/didn't prioritize contact from you") or clearly state their opinion that they are a victim of circumstance.

Comment: @Tyler: The word "sorry" doesn't always mean you are apologizing. It can also be used to express empathy. Take, _"I'm sorry to hear your mother died,"_ for example. "I'm sorry I missed your call" is pretty much a [standard](https://www.google.com/#q=sample+phone+messages+%22sorry+I+missed+your+call%22) voicemail greeting; I wouldn't get wrapped around the axle about the apology part of it.

Answer (score -3):

I am sorry I am in a meeting I will call you back after finishing

Comment: This would work if you answered the call and had to hang up immediately, but not so well if (as the question states) you didn't answer at all.